# How to alter user's input?

Tags: forms

I have a form to get some user input in Drupal. I want to add some prefix to the user input.

For example, the user enters "Laptop"; I want to save it in the database as *resource_Laptop*. I want to add the prefix before the validation is done, to avoid it fails.

How do I do this? Will `hook_form_alter()` help me here?

I have used this method, but not satisfied with this hack.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(){
  drupal_add_js("
    (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {                    
        $('.field-suffix').hide();  
        $('#edit-submit').click(function(){
        var s = $('#edit-machine-name').val();

        if (s.indexOf('_resources') == −1) {
          $('#edit-machine-name').val($('#edit-machine-name').val() + '_resources');
        }
      });   
    })(jQuery);", 'inline');
}
```

Comment: Since your db table already has a column for resources, why do you need to prepend 'resource_' to the content?

Comment: The validate handlers are the first to be called by FAPI after a submit. So it will be difficult to have the prefix added beforhand. May be you want explain why you want to validate something you are adding as a post process and is not entered by the user anyway. If you want to make sure your prefixing code works corrent it would be better to think about writing a simple test.

Comment: @paul-m... actually I am adding some data in taxonomy table and want to make my data unique by adding resources_ prefix to taxonomy vocabulary. It gives me error for machine-name already exist and which is actually added vocabulary by taxonomy so in my module as I am using the same taxonomy tables to save my data.

Comment: What form are you altering? Why are you altering an existing form, rather than using your own form?

Comment: This whole thing seems like a really bad idea and bad way of implementing. If your only worry is passing validation, then why does it matter whether a string has `resource_` prepended or not? It should still be possible to write a validation for that. Best place to add this, and alter input is in a submit handler. Also don't use `#edit-machine-name` as this can become `#edit-machine-name--2` or `#edit-machine-name--3`. Use a class selector, or add a class through that hook_form_alter

Comment: Just don't do this with javascript. You'd be asking for trouble in my opinion. Investigate form validation callbacks. Make yours run first. Make it change the value.

Comment: As others noted, this approach just leads to bad times. It sounds like you should be asking for an entity reference select list or something concrete in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and add a custom submit handler.

```
function example_form_form_id_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id){
  $form['#submit'][] = 'example_form_id_submit',
}

function example_form_id_submit(&$form,&$form_state){
  $form_state['values']['resource_name'] = 'resource_' . $form_state['values']['resource_name'];
}
```

Comment: This will come to late, since op want's to have the prefix added before validation. Validation handlers are called prior to the submit handlers.

Comment: @karthik... this will still fail my validation. I want to add prefix before validation call. does form_set_value help me here?

Comment: @Umar: how about doing the above in the validation instead of during submit, i.e. ```$form['#validate'][] = 'example_form_id_validate'```, you just have to make sure this validation runs before the rest ..

Comment: @Karthik... Nikhil suggested me same and I tried check my response on his comment.

Comment: can you confirm, the validate function does a call by reference and not by value? If you did a call by reference and doesn't work, you might have to stick to your js hack.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more validation callback handler by giving it the priority(executed first) in `$form['#validate']` and change the values in `$form_state`.